# How to check "test data" accuracy and plot them

Tags: python, testing, keras, model, google-colaboratory

I want to test the accuracy of 11000+ images.
I split the data into two classes ,"Yes" and "No". Then ,split them into 80/20 in training set and test set respectively.

Then I split,the training data again into 80/20 for validation set.

**I create "Yes" and "No" folder for each one,validation set, test set, training set.And keep the data in respective folders.**

Now, I want to train the model in **Google Colab**.

**After train the model, I want to test the "Accuracy" of the "Test Data Set" and plot them with, specificity, sensitivity, accuracy, loss_Function and recall.**

Help need for this. Detailed help will be more appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to post example of your code so we can help

Comment: @Yefet Thanks.

I am giving code in Answer.

Actually, I get the Training/Validation accuracy from the code but I want Test set accuracy.

Which method should I use? Should I use K-fold? then,how to use it? 

Sorry,too many questions.

Answer (score 0):

@Yefet

Code is here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import zipfile
import cv2
import os 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, StratifiedKFold

img = image.load_img("drive/MyDrive/data03/train/no/1 no.jpeg" , target_size=(200, 200))
plt.imshow(img)

class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs={}):
        if (logs.get('accuracy') > .98) & (logs.get('val_accuracy') > .9):
            print("Reached 98% accuracy so cancelling training!")
            self.model.stop_training = True
callbacks = myCallback()

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'drive/MyDrive/data03/train',  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(200, 200),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=128,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'drive/MyDrive/data03/validation',  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(200, 200),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=128,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 150x150 with 3 bytes color
    # This is the first convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The second convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The third convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The fourth convolution
    #tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The fifth convolution
    #tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    # Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value from 0-1 where 0 for 1 class ('horses') and 1 for the other ('humans')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=1,  
      epochs=29,
      validation_data = validation_generator,callbacks=[callbacks])
dir_path = "drive/MyDrive/data03/test"
for i in os.listdir(dir_path):
    img = image.load_img(dir_path+ '//' + i, target_size=(200, 200) )
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
   
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    images = np.vstack([x])

    classes =model.predict(images)
    if classes[0]==0:
        print("NO TUMOR")
    else:
        print("YES ")
```